# json not printing on fs.writeFile method of file system

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, fs

```
var json_response = {};

 fs.writeFile(userUploadedImagePath, imageBuffer.data, function(err ) {

             if (err) {
                 return console.error(err);
             } else {

              json_response['success'] = true;
              json_response['msg'] = 'Uploaded successfully';
              res.json(json_response); // console.log(json_response);  works fine.
            }
          });
```

I am new to node js and working to upload image using fs. and i want to print json if successfully uploaded image. image is successfully uploaded but json not printing and giving following error.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
            <center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You should look at Node.js console log

Comment: but I want to show json of that response.

Comment: Try to look at Node.js `ip:port` not the Nginx

Comment: Is your code above directly within the callback function that knows about `res`? If you have your code in a different function, you'll need to pass `res` as a parameter (or use a callback).

Comment: yes, already in a function e.g.

router.post( '/login', function( req, res, next ) {..........});